# How can I change property control by code?

Tags: wpf-controls

I defined a button by xamp look like:

```
 <Window.Resources>
        <Style x:Key="mybutton" TargetType="Button">
            <Setter Property="Width" Value="200"/>
            <Setter Property="Height" Value="200"/>
            <Setter Property="HorizontalAlignment" Value="Left"/>
            <Setter Property="VerticalAlignment" Value="Top"/>
            <Setter Property="Template">
                <Setter.Value>
                    <ControlTemplate TargetType="Button">
                        <Grid>
                            <Border BorderThickness="5" BorderBrush="#7A2D37" CornerRadius="5">
                                <Rectangle x:Name="myele">
                                    <Rectangle.Fill>
                                        <LinearGradientBrush StartPoint="0 0" EndPoint="1 1">
                                            <GradientStop Color="White" Offset="0.1"></GradientStop>
                                            <GradientStop Color="#28009B" Offset="1"></GradientStop>
                                        </LinearGradientBrush>
                                    </Rectangle.Fill>
                                </Rectangle>
                            </Border>
                            <ContentPresenter HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center"></ContentPresenter>
                        </Grid>
                    </ControlTemplate>
                </Setter.Value>
            </Setter>
        </Style>
    </Window.Resources>
    <Grid>
        <Button Margin="100" Style="{StaticResource mybutton}" Click="Button_Click"></Button>
    </Grid>
```

And Button_click event:

```
 private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            Button btn = (Button)sender;
            btn.BorderBrush = Brushes.Yellow;
            btn.BorderThickness = new Thickness(30);
        }
```

But when I click the button, the border did not change.

Could you give me your advance. Thank you verry much.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the `ControlTemplate`, use `{TemplateBinding ...}` for `BorderBrush` and `BorderThickness`. And provide those default values via `Setter`. Then you can change them by code.

```
<Style x:Key="mybutton" TargetType="Button">
    <Setter Property="Width" Value="200"/>
    <Setter Property="Height" Value="200"/>
    <Setter Property="HorizontalAlignment" Value="Left"/>
    <Setter Property="VerticalAlignment" Value="Top"/>

    <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="#7A2D37"/>
    <Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="5"/>

    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="Button">
                <Grid>
                    <Border BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}" BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}" CornerRadius="5">
                        <Rectangle x:Name="myele">
                            <Rectangle.Fill>
                                <LinearGradientBrush StartPoint="0 0" EndPoint="1 1">
                                    <GradientStop Color="White" Offset="0.1"></GradientStop>
                                    <GradientStop Color="#28009B" Offset="1"></GradientStop>
                                </LinearGradientBrush>
                            </Rectangle.Fill>
                        </Rectangle>
                    </Border>
                    <ContentPresenter HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center"></ContentPresenter>
                </Grid>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>
```